# How can I counter enemies with a battlehammer?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm getting massacred each time I encounter someone with a battle hammer, they almost three shot me.

What is the best approach to stay alive against those enemies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use my shield and bash them during the wind up. This helps stagger them so that I can whoop it on. Try blocking with a shield or a two-handed weapon, while they wind up hold the block buttton and hit the attack button at the same time to bash them, see if it staggers them or not.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few options, but it depends on your character's build.

- Shield bash them.
- Stay at distance and use destruction magic (dual cast+impact to stagger).
- Craft better armor.
- Brew some paralyzing poison.
- Use Calm or Fear spells to stop them from hitting you.
- Are you a Nord? Try your Battle Cry to fear them.
- Use a dragon shout, like Unrelenting Force to knock them over, or Ice Form to freeze them in place, or even the Disarm shout, which makes them drop their hammer.